# Creat new menu items link in menu like create new Content Type does

Tags: 7, routes

When create a new Content Type, several new menu links will created and show in the management menu, such as `node/add/article` and `admin/structure/types/manage/article`.

```
Add content
    -- Article
    -- Page
```

How can I implement similar functionality within my custom module?

```
Sites
  -- Site Name A  (link to site/1)
  -- Site Name B  (link to site/2)
```

My `hook_menu()` implements code:

```
$items['site/%'] = array(
  // ...
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_site_view',
  // ...
);
```

I have tried to use `_load()` and `_to_arg()`, but doesn't work or maybe I just not use them correctly.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['site/%mymodule_site'] = array(
        // ...
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_site_view',
        // ...
    );
}

function mymodule_site_load($sid) {
    // load site object from database
    $site = ...
    return $site;
}

function mymodule_site_to_arg($site) {
    // I guess here I can use site object, but just get %
    return $site->name;
}
```

Can anybody give me on example?

---

I know I can create/delete menu links when create/delete my site object manually. I just want to know if I can user `_load()`, `_to_arg()` or others to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use php code just to create a menu with menu links. You can do it with Drupal Core itself.

See below detailed tutorials that may help you.

[How to create a menu and add links to it in Drupal 7](http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-8-how-create-menu-and-add-links-it-drupal-7)

[Advanced Drupal 7 menu settings, how to create parent child menu links](http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-10-advanced-drupal-7-menu-settings-how-create-parent-child-menus-node)

[Create Drop Down Menus in Drupal 7 Using Nice Menus module](http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-18-create-drop-down-menus-drupal-7-using-nice-menus-module)

If you want to do it specifically using Custom Code then your callback function should call [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) with link as an argument.

Comment: I don't want to use admin ui to create menu items manually. I want to create them in my custom module programmatically, when create a new site, a new menu item will be created.